# Products ETA in days, months and year in PHP

Tags: php, product

I’m working on a products Estimated Time of Arrival (ETA) for our products page and I am having difficulties to get the idea to work.

My PHP script goes like:

```
$now = new DateTime(date("y:m:j",time()));
$eta = new DateTime($row['ArrivalDate']);
$diff = $now->diff($eta);
```

Then this is what I want to archive
    If $diff < 30 days then out “within 30 days”

```
If $diff = or > 60days then output “2 months”

If $diff = or > 90 days then output “3 months”

If $diff > 365 days then output “over a year”

If $diff = 25 December  then output “Date to be confirmed”
```

In the ETA column I want to display the ETA as “2 months”

Please help, im no PHP guru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you headed in the right direction. You will need to work out the logic of the ifelseif or a [switch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) on your own, you should be able to handle that.

```
$ArrivalDate = '2013-05-21';


$now = new DateTime("now");
$eta = new DateTime($ArrivalDate);
$diff = $now->diff($eta);
//
$diffDays = $diff->format('%d');
$diffMonths = $diff->format('%m');
$diffYears = $diff->format('%y');


if ( $diffYears !='0' )
{
    echo 'over a year';
}
if ( $diffDays < '31' )
{
    echo 'within the next 30 days (' . $diffDays . '  days)';
}
if ( $diffMonths >= '1' )
{
    echo 'within ' . $diffMonths . ' months';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. so far let me work on it. input appreciated.